# jquery - Compare old and new value after timer

Tags: jquery, compare, setinterval

I've been struggeling with this problem for a while. I bet the solution is pretty easy, so here's the point.
I have a number which I update using setinterval.
After this , I want to check if this number is higher or lower than the number before it's refreshed. If it's higher, it has to show an arrow up, or the other way round. (But I got that covered already, just need the comparison)

Here's what I have until now:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var $omzetvandaag = $("#omzetvandaag").text();

    $("#omzetvandaag").load("index.php #omzetvandaag");

//some code for the comparison 

}, 5000 )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using a swap variable that keeps track of the old value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var omzetvandaag;
setInterval(function () {

    omzetvandaag = $("#omzetvandaag").text();
    var oldData = omzetvandaag;
    $("#omzetvandaag").load("index.php #omzetvandaag");
   // compare oldData and omzetvandaag
//some code for the comparison 

}, 5000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters when calling the setInterval

```
setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)
```

And one of those parameteres can be your previous value, which will be compared inside the setInterval().